# python image search function sends small image

Tags: python, python-requests

i am trying to make a program to search for images, but the function sends small images. how can i fix this? (for example, if the original image is 1920x1080, it will reduce to something like 192x108)

```
def search_image(key):

  url = "https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=" + key.replace(" ", "+") + "&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64j69i60l3.400j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
  headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}

  req = Request(url, headers=headers)
  page = urlopen(req)

  bs = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
  images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.*gstatic.com.*')})

  i = 0

  for img in images:
    i += 1
    if i > 10: i = 10
  for img in images:
    ret = randint(0, i)
    if ret == 1:
      return img['src']
    else: i -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the image with the help of an image library.

`import Image as image`

`image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)`

Comment: oh, ok. where can i find a library like that?